# UWP Navigation Pane Issues

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, hamburger-menu

I am looking for a way to create a navigation pane using SplitView and other XAML controls.

I have tried creating something like the code below, but I failed as the controls aren't placed precisely in the center (vertically).

Also the buttons have this weird default animation that skews them when they are clicked. I want to turn it off but I don't know how.

All in all, I want to create a hamburger menu that is similar to Start menu in Windows 10 Anniversary Update. All opinions would be pretty appreciated.

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <SplitView x:Name="hamburgerMenu" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="319" DisplayMode="CompactOverlay">
        <SplitView.Pane>
            <StackPanel>
                <Button x:Name="HamburgerButton" Width="320"  Height="48" Click="HamburgerButtonClick" BorderThickness="0" Background="{x:Null}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="-8,0,0,0">
                        <TextBlock Width="48" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Text="&#xE700;" TextAlignment="Center" Margin="0,1,0,0" />
                        <TextBlock Text="MENU" Margin="0,0,0,0" FontWeight="Bold" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Button>
                <Button x:Name="TasksButton" Width="320"  Height="48" BorderThickness="0" Background="{x:Null}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="-8,0,0,0">
                        <TextBlock Width="48" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Text="&#xE133;" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                        <TextBlock Text="Tasks" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Button>
                <Button x:Name="ArchivedButton" Width="320"  Height="48" BorderThickness="0" Background="{x:Null}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="-8,0,0,0">
                        <TextBlock Width="48" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Text="&#xE73A;" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                        <TextBlock Text="Archived" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </SplitView.Pane>
    </SplitView>
</Grid>
```

Here is what I want to achieve:

[image: Windows Start Menu]

Screenshots: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCsff.jpg

Comment: You may want to create a new question about the white bar at the top of your app, as that is probably a separate issue. I would also post a screenshot of what the code currently produces

Comment: I've edited the post. Screenshots at the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MessiKing's Template 10 is a good idea and will save you a lot of time. No doubt in that. But that doesn't help you learn how `XAML` handles controls because they are all handled already by experts. However if you want to learn how it works in pure `XAML` without any 3rd Party Libraries, see below.

**Your `XAML` will look something like below**

```
<SplitView x:Name="hamburgerMenu" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" OpenPaneLength="150" DisplayMode="CompactOverlay" IsPaneOpen="True">
    <SplitView.Pane>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Button x:Name="HamburgerButton"  Click="HamburgerButtonClick" Style="{StaticResource TextBlockButtonStyle}" FontWeight="Bold" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
                    <TextBlock FontSize="20" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Text="&#xE700;" TextAlignment="Center" Padding="5"  />
                    <TextBlock Text="MENU" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="15,0"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Button>
            <Grid Grid.Row="1" x:Name="btmtp" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Button x:Name="TasksButton" Style="{StaticResource TextBlockButtonStyle}" Grid.Row="1">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <TextBlock FontSize="20" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Text="&#xE133;" TextAlignment="Center" Padding="5"  />
                    <TextBlock Text="Tasks" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="15,0"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Button>
            <Button x:Name="ArchivedButton" Style="{StaticResource TextBlockButtonStyle}" Grid.Row="2">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <TextBlock FontSize="20" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Text="&#xE73A;" TextAlignment="Center" Margin="5" />
                    <TextBlock Text="Archived" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="15,0"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Button>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </SplitView.Pane>
</SplitView>
```

**Output**

[image]

Now for the styling for buttons. Default Styling provided by Microsoft includes a `StaticResource` called `TextBlockButtonStyle` which will change your button styling to that of a `TextBlock`. Take a look at this.

Also there is a reason why I wrapped the List Items inside a Grid. because if you change

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1" x:Name="btmtp" VerticalAlignment="Top">
```

to

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1" x:Name="btmtp" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
```

you will see it something like below.

[image]

Good Luck and Happy Coding.

Comment: Thank you. It's the exact answer I needed.

Comment: Where to find the HamburgerButtonClick event handler detail?

Comment: @usefulBee Use Tapped event on `HamburgerButton` and in that just say `hamburgerMenu.IsPaneOpen=!hamburgerMeNu.IsPaneOpen`

Answer (score 1):

Dziewulski,

If you want to make a hamburgerMenu, using Template 10 would save you much time.

When you install the Template 10 in visual studio, you will be easy to create a project which contained a hamburgerMenu in it.

Please refer to these videos for details:[Template 10 for Windows 10 Apps](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Visual-Studio-Toolbox/Template10-for-Windows-10-Apps)

[Template 10: How to Build Your Universal Windows App](https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/DevRadio/DR1622)

Answer (score 1):

try the UWP Toolkit from Microsoft. It contains a hamburger menu:
https://github.com/Microsoft/UWPCommunityToolkit